# PHP download pdf file

Tags: php

I am trying to download file from a webservice that i build in php:

```
    $file = "pdffile.pdf";
    if (file_exists($file)) {
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
        ob_clean();
        flush();
        readfile($file);
        exit;
    }
```

When i try this code in my browser, Firefox downloads the file (with the file name), but when i tried to open the file in my Mac OS the preview app gives this error:

```
It may be damaged or use a file format that Preview doesn’t recognize.
```

Any idea what is wrong with this?

Comment: Your code checked out for me. I think it may be a local issue and not server-side. Or, the file that was created/uploaded isn't a good one to start with. Also make sure that the PDF is inside the same folder you're running your code from; by the looks of no exact path being set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you ran into the case where the file didn't exist (because you have no path, just the name) and so nothing was returned. Add an else:

```
else
{
  header('Content-Type: text/html');
  echo "File didn't exist";
}
```

For your filename, use a path relative to the PHP file, like:

```
$file = "./pdffile.pdf";
```

or use the absolute path like:

```
$file = "c:/pdffile.pdf";
```

Also, for your PDF content-type, instead of application/octet-stream you might want to use:

```
 header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the following line

header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));

This is normally used if background processing is necessary. It could be that in your case downloading is finished before it should be because specified file size is different to the file.